# no suitable method found for setOnClickListener(<anonymous OnItemClickListener>) method View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener) is not applicable

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

ArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayList);

```
    myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

    myListView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Aathiyagamam.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:
**Change .setOnClickListener to .setOnItemClickListener**

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Aathiyagamam.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
```

**I suggest you to use RecyclerView instead of ListView. Check the difference [here](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-listview-recyclerview)**